# Performance of drawing one VBO with different data in one frame

Tags: c++, opengl

My current setup is I have one vbo with some size created with glGenBuffer. I am drawing
several different stripes in one frame to do that I use glBufferSubData.
So in one frame I do this

```
//stipe one 
glBindBuffer(buffer)    
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, size, data1);
//updaing shader uniforms
glDrawArrays(_drawMode, 0, _verticesCount1);

//stipe two 
glBindBuffer(buffer)    
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, size, data2);
//updaing shader uniforms
glDrawArrays(_drawMode, 0, _verticesCount2);

//and so on
```

I know that opengl is async and my question is should I use seperate vbo for each stripe because opengl (or graphics driver) can start draw them simultaneously or this is not how it works at all and there is no difference?

Comment: Are the vertex arrays `data1` and `data2` static or does the data change continuously? If the data doesn't change then use 2 VBOs instead of loading the data to the data store of the buffer in every frame.